# 2010 Camry rear reading light bulb replacement

Tags: replace

One of these bulbs burnt out. I'm not much of a mechanic. I need to get it changed. So, is it doable or do I have to take it to a shop? I don't even know what bulb goes there as I'm not sure how can I remove the bulb. Once I have the bulb, I can go buy another and then replace it.
If this is doable without going to a shop, then can you please tell me the steps for replacing this bad bulb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll preface this by saying I have never changed this bulb in a Camry before ... with that said, the replacement bulb should be a 194 or 168 or 2825 (different numbers for same basic bulb). It looks something like this:

[image: Bulb Image]

Here are the steps I found at [this site](http://www.toyotanation.com/forum/104-5th-6th-generation-2002-2006-2007-2011/271120-diy-rear-map-lights-removal-w-moon-roof.html):

1) First you want to remove base from roof liner.

There are 2 clips in the rear...2 in front...and 2 on sides (6 total). Put screwdriver between base and roof liner and pry down and out while pulling on base. Start with sides then work around.

[image: Outer clips]

2) Remove cover from base.

There are 10 clips holding cover to base. Put screwdriver between base clip and cover and pry out to unhook (make sure they are staying out) then work your way around 1 by 1. There are 2 clips in the middle...1 you can unhook like others. Other middle clip you cant see but you will need to wait until you get all other clips unhooked then just pull apart the last clip will just unhook itself.

[image: Cover Clips]

3) Remove bulb from bottom and replace with bulb of choice.

You can now access bulb and replace it. After replacing bulb just clip cover back to base and base back to roof. Done

For a full list of bulbs for your vehicle, look at [this site](http://www.elightbulbs.com/2010-Toyota-Camry-Replacement-Light-Bulbs).

EDIT: I realized after I posted you were looking for the installation of the reading lights in the back, not the front map lights, so updated to reflect. Also, readded first cover image as it didn't show up for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the pics and the link. I went to that site and the guys is replace stock bulbs with LED ones. I wonder how can you do that. Doesn't the bulb need to be of the same wattage and what not?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Forgot to mention here that I got them replaced with LEDs some time back.